# Oracle 11g configuration with Enterprise manager on windows 2008 standard R2

Tags: oracle11g, database-installation

I am trying to install Oracle 11g on windows 2008 standard server R2 (as standalone). I get successful installation as I can connect to sqlplus. But when I try to run the "Enterprise manager" through the EM url on https I see a login page...I try to enter "SYS" then password then select role as SysDBA" and then I get the following error.

"Internal Error has occurred. Check the log file for details."

I have been searching forums like crazy since last one week and tried all solutions but no luck. Can anyone guide me here how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, the following command solved it:

```
emca -config dbcontrol db -repos recreate -ORACLE_HOSTNAME hostname -SID orcl -PORT 1521 -ORACLE_HOME $ORACLE_HOME -DBDNMP_PWD sys
```

Comment: @wetland I've just improved the answer, all greetings should be to Mohaimen ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check before login to Oracle 11g Admin Page.
Check that all the windows related to Oracle must be closed.
After this, restart the services and try to login.