# Oracle enterprise manager 11g internal error?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, windows-10, oracle-enterprise-manager

I've successfully installed oracle 11g enterprise edition on my 64bit machine with windows 10. After i access `https://localhost:1158/em` and enter username and password correctly i get an error as `Internal Error has occurred. Check the log file for details.` screen shot is as follows:

[image]

Any help in resolving this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: is any information in log files?

Comment: Possibly related: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20997129/266304), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6179053/266304), and [this DBA question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/62540/847) mentions where the logs are. Without log info we have no more idea what is wrong than you. But this doesn't seem to be [on-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: i don't see any information in log files. I've set environment variable for `ORACLE_UNQNAME` only. Tell me if i have to set any other environment variables?